# JDBC connect to MYSQL not working with Codename one

Tags: java, mysql, codenameone

I have created a simple login form in Java, to connect to a mysql database. It works a Jframe form. However, when i insert the file into the Codename one application, it does not accept the Jdbc connection. What should be the alternative?
Can i change the Jdbc to another method, in order to perform the queries, and connect to the codename one application after i insert the correct credentials, same way it works here?

My code:

loginform.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package packagelogin2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author ksak
 */
public class Java_Form_Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Javaloginform
     */
    public Java_Form_Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */

    Timer timer1 = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            if(jPanel_Message.getHeight() != 105 ) 

            {
            jPanel_Message.setBounds(0,0,Java_Form_Login.this.getSize().width,jPanel_Message.getHeight() + 5);
            if(jPanel_Message.getHeight() == 105){
            timer1.stop();

            }          
            }
        }     
    });

    Timer timer2 = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            if(jPanel_Message.getHeight() != 0 ) 

            {
            jPanel_Message.setBounds(0,0,Java_Form_Login.this.getSize().width,jPanel_Message.getHeight() - 5);
            if(jPanel_Message.getHeight() == 105){
            timer2.stop();

            }          
            }
        }     
    });











    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Username = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Password = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField_Username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField_Password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jButton_Login = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel_Message = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel_Message = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton_Ok = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.decode("#bdb76b"));

        Username.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        Username.setText("Username :");

        Password.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        Password.setText("Password:");

        jTextField_Username.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField_Username.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField_UsernameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPasswordField_Password.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordField_PasswordActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jCheckBox1.setText("Show Password");
        jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton_Login.setText("Login");
        jButton_Login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_LoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel_Message.setBackground(java.awt.Color.decode("#3a7595"));

        jLabel_Message.setText("Message: ");

        jButton_Ok.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton_Ok.setText("Ok");
        jButton_Ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_OkActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel_MessageLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel_Message);
        jPanel_Message.setLayout(jPanel_MessageLayout);
        jPanel_MessageLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel_MessageLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel_MessageLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Message)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 308, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Ok, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(98, 98, 98))
        );
        jPanel_MessageLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel_MessageLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel_MessageLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Message)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel_MessageLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Ok, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(Password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField_Username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 133, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton_Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(62, 62, 62))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField_Password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 133, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel_Message, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel_Message, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 175, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(Username)
                            .addComponent(jTextField_Username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53))
                    .addComponent(jButton_Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Password)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField_Password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox1))
                .addGap(81, 81, 81))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField_UsernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                   

    private void jPasswordField_PasswordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                       

    private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

         Connection connection;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/admin_1?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","user1","password1");
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `table1` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
            ps.setString(1, jTextField_Username.getText());
            ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Password.getPassword()));
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            if(result.next()){
                jLabel_Message.setText("Login Successful");
                jLabel_Message.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                timer1.start();
            }
            else{
                jLabel_Message.setText("Invalid Username Or Password");
                jLabel_Message.setForeground(Color.RED);
                timer1.start();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Java_Form_Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }                                             

    private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
           if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
            jPasswordField_Password.setEchoChar((char)0);
        }else{
          jPasswordField_Password.setEchoChar('*');
        }
    }                                          

    private void jButton_OkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        timer2.start();




    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Java_Form_Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Java_Form_Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Java_Form_Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Java_Form_Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Java_Form_Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Password;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Username;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Login;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Ok;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_Message;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_Message;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField_Password;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_Username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

It works as a single class. However, after i put the package in codename one, the error:

```
 ΜΜ packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login jButton_LoginActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:110)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login.jButton_LoginActionPerformed(Java_Form_Login.java:248)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login.access$400(Java_Form_Login.java:24)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login$6.actionPerformed(Java_Form_Login.java:131)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Ιουν 20, 2018 3:03:42 ΜΜ packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login jButton_LoginActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:mysql://62.210.149.54/admin_akmi17?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:110)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login.jButton_LoginActionPerformed(Java_Form_Login.java:248)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login.access$400(Java_Form_Login.java:24)
    at packagelogin2.Java_Form_Login$6.actionPerformed(Java_Form_Login.java:131)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those API's aren't supported in Codename One and for good reason. You can't connect to an SQL database on a server from a mobile device. This will destroy security, performance and reliability.

Further reading:

- https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html
- https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html
- https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-part-2.html

Comment: I followed java mysql database part 2. I reached it until the "test uri", which works successfully. How do i use it for the login app? The part "The Client App" using the Xataface is unclear.

Comment: I suggest asking in that blog post as I don't know much about Xatafaces and didn't write that post

Comment: I see. Any alternatives to Xataface? All i want is to do is connect the database in the app the same way as i do in Java.

Comment: See the second article that details the Java based approach. You can't connect to a remote SQL database directly from the device. Doing that would be a HUGE security risk and performance problem.